# Best batching size choice

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In Microsoft's [documents regarding CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming) it has been said that Stored Procedure and UDF Programming are good when you have a batch save or submit, but it hasn't said anything regarding batch size/record count.

> Batching – Developers can group operations like inserts and submit them in bulk. The network traffic latency cost and the store overhead to create separate transactions are reduced significantly.

Is there any limits? What is the best practice?

For example lets say I have a million record that I'd like to save and each record is 2-4KB. I think it is not a good idea to call the SP with 3 GB of data. :)

Should I go for  1000 rows in 1 call (~3MB) or is it still too big/small?

***P.S**: Since it has been promised to complete a write action in less than 15 Milliseconds, I would assume that 1000 records should take less than 15 seconds and 5000 records less than 75  seconds which both are still valid duration.

Answer (score 0):

I will say, you should experiment to come up with the correct batch size.

However, remember sprocs can run only for 5 seconds. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#bounded-execution for how to handle this from code.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

There a few things you need to consider while doing Batching.

When you use a stored procedure to do Batch upsert, it can only work on a single partition.

If each of your record is 4 KB, then a write operation would consume around 4 times 6 RUs/sec = 24 RUs/sec for a single write.
A single physical partition can only have a maximum of 10K RUs, which means you could at best you could insert 416 documents/sec.
This is assuming there is no additional cost of indexing and there are no other writes happening to the same physical partitions.

Batching definitely saves on the network hops you make.
But you should consider the below when you are using batching:

1. Executing a stored procedure would consume some extra RUs that will be consumed from the RUs that are allocated to your partition.
2. If a stored procedure throws an un-handled error , then the whole transaction will be rolled back. Which means the RUs are used up with out adding any data.
   So you need to do good exception handling and if there are failures after executing half of the batch, re-try only for the rest.
3. The code of the Stored procedure does not necessarily run as good as the document db internal code.
4. Also there is bounded execution limit of 5 secs before the transaction is killed.